# Extract and replace all images from paragraph

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing

i have this html content :

```
<p><img src="##" />
</p>
<p>

<img src="##" />
</p>
<p>
</p>
<p class="ss"><a href="ss">
    <img src="####" />
</a></p>
```

i want to extract all paragraphs and all their images and reformat the html so i can have images first then the folowing paragraph this is an example :

```
<img src="##" /><p>
</p>
<img src="##" />
<p>


</p>
<p>
</p>
<img src="####" />
<p class="ss"><a href="ss">

</a></p>
```

i tried something but it won't work :

```
$result = preg_replace('/(<p\b[^><]*)>(.+?)(<img([^>]*)\/>)(.+?)(<\/p>)/is', '$2 $4', $text);
```

Comment: This would be hard to do with an html parser, let alone using regex.

Comment: that's what i want, only regex

Comment: Why the insistence on regex? This would be much easier with [SimpleXML](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2988730

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this work for me , it looks for each paragraph that contains any content and an image, so i can match all images and their containing paragraphs.

```
$pattern = '/(<p\b[^><]*>)(((?!<\/p>).?)*)(<img.*?\/\>)(((?!<\/p>).?)*)(<\/p>)/s';
```

Comment: That's nice. Care to explain what it does?

Answer (score 0):

This is very crude and may match more than you want it to, but in very simple scenarios, this may work:

```
$result = preg_replace('/(<p[^>]*>)(.*?)(<img[^>]*>)/is', '$3$1$2', $text);
```

This is probably better:

```
$result = preg_replace('/(<p[^>]*>)([^<]*)(<img[^>]*>)/is', '$3$1$2', $text);
```

Comment: Seems to work how I designed it.  It wasn't meant to pull img tags when nested.  It could, but then it would also incorrectly pull some images that it shouldn't.  The assumption I made based on the OP's examples is that the img tag would immediately follow the p tag opening, and I only pull those.  In your example, you pulled an img tag out of an anchor tag, which would then render the anchor useless and the img unclickable.

Comment: In that case, you would probably want to pull both the anchor tag and img tag out of the p, but that isn't what he asked for -- better to be safe than to go mangling the source when situations arise that are undefined.